# opensource project like visual nhibernate

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I need to map 100 tabels for fluent nhibernate. I can do this by hand or by some tool. I found http://www.slyce.com/VisualNHibernate/ but it is not free. Does anyone know any free tool?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visual NHibernate has a free 30-day trial. This should give you enough time to generate what you need.

**Update:** Visual NHibernate has now been open-sourced. See: [Visual NHibernate open source announcement](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/nhibernate-development/RRjdjFjOmbs/discussion)

Answer (score 3):

[NHibernate Mapping Generator](http://nmg.codeplex.com/) should work too.